# Broad claim of US Patent 7,404,278 and available prior art

Tags: prior-art-request, chemistry, us7404278, package-making

Does anyone have any prior art for [U.S. Patent 7,404,278](http://www.google.com/patents/US7404278).  The patent describes a method of siliconization for syringes, with the novelty of the method being asserted as "subjecting the siliconized syringe to a temperature treatment of approximately 120 degrees C to 300 degrees C and more" to bond the silicone to the glass surface of the syringe.  Subjecting the siliconized syringe to an elevated temperature, to effectively "cure" the silicone to the surface, has been known in the industry but I am unable to find the relevant references for this.

Answer (score 1):

Patent number: 6447610
Filing date: Jul 18, 2000 was considered by the examiner. It mentions silicone oil but not curing. A later filed application says the present invention won't work because the adhesive holding the needle to the syringe will not stand up to the cure temp.